# Подмена индексного файла в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Приветствую, Коллеги!

Прошу помощи в битве с htaccess файлом.

Имеется проект с директорией public. В директории находится index.php и поддиректория build/project/, в которой располагается файл index.html
Пытаюсь понять, каким образом возможно при входе на http://site.ru/ можно загружать страницу и ее ресурсы по пути /public/build/project/index.html, а при входе на http://site.ru/old/ - подключаться к текущему файлу index.php

Благодарен за любую помощь!

P.S. править конфиг apache возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

но ведь на `http://site.ru/old/` все ресурсы, к примеру 
`http://site.ru/old/images/logo.png` тоже должно грузиться с 
`/public/build/project/images/logo.png`.

т.е все запросы по этому префиксу должны перенаправлятся в поддиректорию?

лучшее решение в данном случаи думаю - это сделать поддомен old.site.ru 
и тогда все возможные проблемы отпадут.

Comment: У меня в распоряжении только htaccess файл. Никаких поддоменов или правок конфигов не предусмотрено :( Иначе решил бы уже проблему давно

Comment: RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ build/project/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: в конце htaccess добавить, должно работать.

Comment: Не должно. Выходит обычный редирект. А мне нужна подмена рут директории, фактически

Comment: @AndrewKoshkin почему бы не сделать symlink: ln -s full_path/build/project full_path/old

Comment: @AndrewKoshkin это не редирект (хедер с 301 кодом), а forward. Т.е клиента ни куда не перекидывает, а сервер отдает контент по этому указанному урлу.

Comment: Проблем при всем этом масса, в том числе и с поддиректориями. Есть проект с папкой public, она и есть рут. Внутри public имеется файл index.php и несколько папок для этого index.php (css/*,images/*). Внутри папки public так же есть папка new в которой свой index.php, в которой свои папки css и images. Вот задача стоит делать "подмену" одного интерфейса другим при входе на / -> new/index.php и /old -> index.php

Comment: через virtual hosts тогда прям указывать директорию.